# Haskell -- Timing out computations in the Rand monad

Tags: haskell, random, timeout, monads, lazy-evaluation

I want to evaluate random computations in Haskell with a timeout using the `Control.Monad.Random` library. The following works just fine:

```
ghci> import System.Timeout
ghci> import Control.Monad.Random
ghci> timeout 1000 . evalRandIO $ getRandomR (True, False)
Just True
```

However, this approach does not seem to work if we have a computation of type `Rand StdGen a` that never terminates (i.e. evaluates to bottom). For example:

```
ghci> let f = f :: Rand StdGen Bool
ghci> timeout 1000 $ evalRandIO f
Just
```

Here GHCI prints "Just " and then hangs indefinitely trying to evaluate `f`. Can someone who knows more about the Haskell runtime than I do explain why this happens, and how to get around it? My guess is that the expression `evalRandIO f` is evaluated to WHNF and so `timeout 10` thinks the computation is going to terminate, but I really have no idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might make more sense if you were to do something like

```
> Just x <- timeout 1000 $ evalRandIO f
> :t x
x :: Bool
> x
Interrupted.
```

The computation itself is completing, namely it's reaching WHNF, so `timeout` does not catch it.  The `timeout 1000` function itself completes and returns `Just undefined`.  An example where you *can* get `timeout` to catch a bottom evaluation would be

```
> import Control.DeepSeq
> :set +m    -- Multiline mode
> let f :: Bool
|     f = f
|
> timeout 1000000 $ deepseq f (return f)
Nothing
```

You'll see that it hangs for a second, then returns `Nothing` when `deepseq` does not finish evaluating `f` so it can perform `return f`.

So yes, your problem is stemming from the fact that `f = f` gets evaluated to WHNF instead of NF.  In order to force NF, you need to use something like `deepseq`.  Another possibly simpler example would be to just use the `$!` operator, such as:

```
> let f :: Rand StdGen Bool
|     f = f
|
> timeout 1000000 $ evalRandIO $! f
Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you! I clearly have a lot to learn about seq/deepseq and the Haskell runtime.

Comment: @user3873438 To be fair, I had to load up a GHCi session to figure it out myself.  Laziness causes some interesting problems, but most of the time you don't even have to think about it.  It's mostly when you get to problems that require things to happen in a particular order that you need to start worrying about strictness, and in this case you wanted `evalRandIO f` to occur before the end of `timeout 1000` was reached.  With a relationship like that, it's important to be explicit with strictness, which is what `deepseq` and `$!` do.

Comment: You also need to worry about laziness for space leaks and parallelism.