# Haskell -- Forcing strict evaluation with a weird, recursive type

Tags: haskell, timeout, lazy-evaluation

I [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24936917/haskell-timing-out-computations-in-the-rand-monad) asked a question about how to force strict evaluation to create a timeout. Using `seq`/`$!` is sufficient most of the time, and `deepseq` works for anything that is a member of `NFData`, but what if we are using a weird recursive type? Suppose we have the following:

```
import Control.DeepSeq
import Control.Monad.Random
import Data.Maybe
import System.Timeout

newtype A = A { runA :: A -> Int -> Rand StdGen Bool }

-- a call to runA with this as the first input will always terminate
example1 :: A
example1 = A (\_ i -> (if i > 0 then getRandomR (True, False) else return False))

-- a call to runA with this as the first input will never terminate
example2 :: A
example2 = A (\_ _ -> runA example2 example2 0)

-- here it depends on the other input 
-- will terminate with example1, not with example2 or 3
example3 :: A
example3 = A (\a _ -> runA a a 0)
```

Can we write a timeout function that determines whether some value `x` of type `A` will terminate within a given amount of time when we call `runA x x 0`? We can try using `seq` like so:

```
testTimeout :: A -> IO (Maybe Bool)
testTimeout x = timeout 1000 . evalRandIO $! runA x x 0
```

However, this does not work for `example2` and `example3` because the call to `runA` gets evaluated to WHNF, but then hangs because the computation never finishes. Trying the same thing with `deepseq` (i.e. `$!!`) won't even compile, because we need an `NFData` instance for `Rand StdGen Bool`. So, how can we implement this instance such that the strict evaluation/timeout works as intended? Or is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `timeout` just executes the action in a certain amount of time without evaluating the result. It does not evaluate the resulting insides. That is okay. If we use

```
(>>= (return $!)) :: Monad m => m a -> m a
```

As you know, return creates a value of type `m a`. By doing `return $!`, we are saying that we won't make `m a`, and therefore complete the action, until the result is evaluated. Here is a more verbose function.

```
evalM m = do
    result <- m
    result `seq` return result
```

You could also do this with NFData (which is not necessary for `Bool` but would be if you where using `[a]` instead) you could do:

```
(>>= (return $!!)) :: (Monad m, NFData a) => m a -> m a
```

More verbosely:

```
forceM m = do
    result <- m
    result `deepseq` return result
```

Comment: The OP is already using `($!)` and can't use `($!!)` unless they provide an `NFData A` instance.

Comment: Thank you! I'm probably going to be re-reading this answer several times until it really clicks. For those following along, the correct way to use this is `testTimeout x = timeout 1000 . evalM . evalRandIO $ runA x x 0`.

Comment: Ah, but (1) he did not use `$!` in the way I did and (2) he didn't not have `NFData m Bool` but the way I use it only requires `NFData Bool`.

Comment: @user3873438 Just remember, in Haskell, when you execute an action, it may not evaluate its result, and leave it for the next guy. Lazy evaluation is everywhere man, and timeout doesn't mess with that.

Answer (score 1):

Huh.  That is an odd little type there.  Maybe this?

```
instance NFData A where
    rnf (A !runA) = ()

strictify :: A -> A
strictify (A !runA) = A $ \a i -> strictify a `deepSeq` i `deepSeq` runA a i

testTimeout x = timeout 1000 . evalRandIO $! runA x' x' 0
 where x' = strictify x
```

That might even be "too strict" *and* redundantly strict, not sure.